# Matlab. I got some errors

Tags: matlab, indexing

```
l_0=1.5; 
l_1=1.6;  
Lambda_min=2*(1+1)*l_0; 
Lambda_max=2*(1+1)*l_1; 
n_0=linspace(2,2.11,10);
n_1=linspace(2.30,2.50,10);
for i=1:10  
 for j=1:10
   for k=1:10
    l(i) = Lambda_min * ( Lambda_max/Lambda_min)^(i/10)

    sum=sum(l)
    d_0(:,j)= l(i)/((n_0(i)/n_1(i)+1))                
    d_1(:,k)= (n_0(i)/n_1(i))*d_0(:,j)   
    end
   end
 end
```

First of all; I want to find values of l(i) which is a vector, then take the sum of that vector. second, for d_0(:,j) I want to create a matrix so I can plot it later, that takes different values from l(i),n_0,n_1 each time. If I take the values for n_0 and n_1 and put in the for loop I will get index error because it should be logic or integer number.

My matrix is overwritten and do not know how to avoid it. Note, I want in d_0 and d_1 n_0 and n_1 to take values from linspace. for example in the first iteration n_0= 2 n_1= 2.30 then second iteration take the next value in linspace.

I tried to see the value of n_0(i) and does it give me 10 iterations. It gives me more that that overwritten.

Comment: You created a variable 'sum(i)' using a function sum...Do not name variables after functions. Also, l(i) should not be in the k and j loop, as it doesn't change with those iterations. l(1) is one value, so the sum of l(1) will give you l(1). You have a lot of basic matlab errors.

Comment: Please try to use a matlab debugger to understand your code better which may enable you to solve the problem yourself or to ask a better question. Your title (_I got some errors_) does not tell anything about your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
l_0=1.5; 
l_1=1.6; 

Lambda_min = 4*l_0; 
Lambda_max = 4*l_1; 

n_0 = linspace(2,2.11,10) % don't add semicolon so you can check this is giving 10 values
n_1 = linspace(2.30,2.50,10) %

for i=1:10  
    l(i) = Lambda_min * ( Lambda_max/Lambda_min)^(i/10) % should give you 10 values
 end

 d_0= l./((n_0./n_1+1)); % This will only give you a vector, not a matrix.               
 d_1= (n_0./n_1).*d_0;   

Lsum = sum(l); % should give you one value
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. It does give my 10 values for n_0. I got error message **In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same**. Error in a_new_attempt_to_calculate (line 13)
    d_1(i)= (n_0(i)/n_1(i))*d_0(:,i).. Also, I got error for last line Lsum = sum(l). This is the message **Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.**

Comment: Sorry, it should be d_0(i) not d_0(:,i). I'll edit that now

Comment: Sure. If this answered your question, accept it as an answer so others know. Otherwise, just comment and let me know what you're still struggling with.

Comment: Sorry it does not work. It seems to me it just take one value from n_0 and n_1. I calculated that be hand and I got the same result. the matrix is overwritten at each iteration.

Comment: You don't have an matrices. You only have vectors. Are you trying to create a matrix using n_0 and n_1?

Comment: These vectors overwritten. How can I avoid that.  Also I tried to find the sum of l . I got error.

Comment: What is being overwritten? everything should be size 1x10, except Lsum which is just 1.

Comment: I am sorry but it does not d_0 size 10x10